# Finding a closed form solution

Tags: summation, sequences-and-series

For the sequence `0 2 8 34 144 ...`

The recurrence relation is:
$$\begin{align*}
E(n) = 4*E(n-1)+E(n-2)
\end{align*}$$

How to calculate the closed form expression for the following summation.
$$\begin{align*}
S(n) = \sum_{i=0}^nE_i
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Have you tried deriving the Binet-type representation of $E(n)$? (Hint: use the characteristic polynomial.) You can then use the formula for a geometric series.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

Answer (score 0):

This is a second-order linear recurrence. The auxillary quadratic here is 
$$\lambda^2 = 4\lambda + 1,$$
so you have
$$\lambda^2 - 4\lambda - 1 = 0.$$
Using the quadratic formula you get the bases
$$\lambda = {4\pm \sqrt{16 + 4}\over 2} = 2\pm \sqrt{5}. $$
Your solution is of the form
$$E(n) = c_0(2 -\sqrt{5})^n + c_1(2 + \sqrt{5})^n.$$
Match the initial conditions to ferret out the constants.

Comment: Can you please tell what you mean by auxiliary quadratic? And how to find the constants $c_0$ and $c_1$ ? PS : I'm a total noob.

Comment: @Protino, you might want to familiarize yourself with how the Binet formula for the Fibonacci numbers is derived. That method is then easily adapted to this case. Also, nc's "auxillary quadratic" is the same as the "characteristic polynomial" I was referring to in my previous comment.

Comment: @Protino  Look into "linear difference equations".

Comment: @Pro, why not type something like "Binet formula Fibonacci derive" into the fantastic search engine of your choice?

Comment: @J.M. lol and thanks. I referred this http://planetmath.org/derivationofbinetformula and found that $c_0$ = $1\over2\sqrt{5}$ and $c_1$ = $-1\over2\sqrt{5}$. But, how to solve $S(n)$?

Comment: @Pro, did you look at my very first comment? I told you to look up the formula for a finite geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ncmathsadist, hoping, this isn't homework

$\sum _{i=1}^n \left(\frac{\left(2-\sqrt{5}\right)^i}{2 \sqrt{5}}-\frac{\left(\sqrt{5}+2\right)^i}{2 \sqrt{5}}\right)=-\frac{\sqrt{5} \left(2-\sqrt{5}\right)^n-3 \left(2-\sqrt{5}\right)^n+\sqrt{5} \left(\sqrt{5}+2\right)^n+3 \left(\sqrt{5}+2\right)^n-2 \sqrt{5}}{2 \sqrt{5} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)}$